# Data Validation Allowing More Than One Entries

Tags: vba, excel

I have written down the lines that follow in order to allow the user to insert more that one entries in a data validated range. So if the dropdown list contains the elements: `x1, x2, x3, .., xn`, then, for any cell in the range, one can select and insert at first `x1` value, then at the same cell select and insert `x3` with the result being: `x1, x3`, and so it goes. 
The problem is that when the user wishes to delete one of the value he gets an excel error saying `the user has restricted the values for this cell`. Therefore, he must delete the entire content of the cell and then select again the values he wants. Can you help improve this with regard to that?

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim rngDV As Range
  Dim oldVal As String
  Dim newVal As String

  If Target.count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

  On Error Resume Next
  Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
  On Error GoTo exitHandler
  If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler
  If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then

 'Column 7 is the one to which is the code is applied
  ElseIf Target.Column = 7 Then

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    newVal = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    oldVal = Target.Value
    Target.Value = newVal
    If oldVal = "" Then
    Else
    If newVal = "" Then

    Else
    Target.Value = oldVal _
     & ", " & newVal

    End If
   End If
 End If

exitHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: so if we delete one part from Range G it should apply in the same cell?

Answer (score 0):

Violating validation through VBA is possible, that's why your code works in the first place. Deleting an entry is a manual action where the cell content (a comma separated list) is being compared to your validation list. 
You could do one of the following:

- use your cell with validation for selection of items only, and write the comma separated selection to a *different* cell.
- write an edit function for the cell - that way the result of the edit will be again written into the cell via VBA.
- add the list (and all possible results from deletions into the validation list as well (very messy though)

Answer (score 0):

try with below

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngDV As Range
    Dim oldVal As String
    Dim newVal As String
    If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngDV = Range("G:G")
        On Error GoTo exitHandler
        If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler
            If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
            ElseIf Target.Column = 7 Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                newVal = Target.Value
                Application.Undo
                oldVal = Target.Value
                Target.Value = newVal
                If oldVal = "" Then
                Else
                If newVal = "" Then
                Else
                Target.Value = oldVal & ", " & newVal
            End If
        End If
    End If
exitHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```